# rest apis for wso2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In the link

http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/10/wsas-hiddedn-services.html I saw WSo2 Soap apis , can I get it's equivalent rest apis. And an example which shows how to pass authentication details. I need this one for wso2 Identity server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Identity server, You can find many management web services API that  can be used for authentication, authorization, user management and so on. Could you let us know the API that you are looking for..  then we can say what is exact web service that you could use. As an example for XACML based authorization, there are "EntitlementService" web service where you can find more details [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/13/pdp-pep-communication-wso2is/). But still rest API is not available for this service. 
Normally it is mentioned these web service API as admin services in WSO2 products.
Currently (With IS 450), It has a rest API for user management based on SCIM where you find them [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS410/Managing+SCIM). However,  you can expose all SOAP based API as Rest API using WSO2 APIM product.

Comment: Thanks @asela, Me requirement is like this. I need to sign up and authenticate ldap user through API, for esb service I need to get oauth token after authentication. So Apis for createuser, login is helpful, your document about SCIM is helpful, is it support for an ldap user?

Comment: Yes..  Identity server can be plugged with any user store. It can be a LDAP,  AD and JDBC...  If you are plugging a your own LDAP server, Please use user-mgt.xml file to configure it...  By default Identity Server is shipped with a embedded LDAP (which is ApacheDS).  Basically when WSOIS is started, LDAP server is started internally. You can use SCIM for creating users (and do user-mgt function with LDAP). If you are looking for OAuth. WSO2IS can  act as OAuth 2.0 Server. You can use resource owner grant type to authenticate user and receive an OAuth access token http://tinyurl.com/lu3bkkb

Comment: Thanks @asela, I have succeed authentication with SCIM and got token back even for ldap user. But user creation not succeding for ldap , this is the curl command I'm give , may I need to give any parameter to specify domain name ? curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"abcd","givenName":"XYZA"},"userName":"user1","password":"testpass","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"abc.com","type":"home"},{"value":"abc_work.com","type":"work"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users

Comment: is there any error in the WSO2 IS logs (console)?  I guess you can follow this http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2012/11/wso2-identity-server-as-scim-service.html ...  If the error with adding attribute to LDAP..  please check that you are using the supported attributes to create use....  if you login to management console of IS...  you can see claim management (Home > Configure>Claim Management > Claim View). Here SCIM claims have been defined. and they have been mapped with attributes...

Comment: the http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2013/06/scim-user-provisioning-with-wso2.html helped me to solve the ldap issue, but now direct user creation not working but ldap works perfectly.

Comment: Dear Asela. I want to work rest API equivalent of changePasswordByUser . this is soap is under UserAdmin wsdl. do you know is there any equivalent for it?