# how to invoke wso2 identification server api

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

wso2 identification server works as identification server, provides authentication and authorization capability. 
In my case, I want to use identification server in following scenario:

client application (C# exe) 
server application (C# IIS web application)

I want my server application can invoke identification server rest api to perform authentication.

Is it possible?
If I can do this, where is api document I can refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring the previous question "[rest apis for wso2 Identity server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186291/rest-apis-for-wso2-identity-server)", currently WSO2 Identity Server mostly based on SOAP APIs.

But you can easily expose these SOAP APIs as REST APIs using WSO2 API Manager or WSO2 ESB.

You can find more details on that in [here](http://darray.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/rest-apis-for-wso2-identity-server/)

HTH,

DarRay